# UISplitview - not from the appdelegate

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to do an IPad app that needs to use UISPlitview. I have found a lot of examples of how to do this but they all come from the starting point of using the AppDelegate. Does anyone have a sample where it is used in the view pushed from a previous view?

Answer (score 0):

In my searches for answers to basic splitviewcontroller questions I have come across your question.  It is a little old now but I thought I would provide an answer for the next person that finds the question in the forum.

If I understand your question you have views and at some stage through user selection you would like to display a splitview on the window, is this correct?

You really have to understand the theory of a splitviewcontroller and also the wishes of Apple on that theory.  When you understand this you will know that what you want to do is not really (or at least at the beginning of 3.2) what Apple would like.  The Splitview should be the rootview of your app. Thus always there and not pushed or added later.

Now if you google long enough you will find examples where people have worked around this. Look at for example "Splitview in tabbarcontroller".  But there are others.

As for a nice tutorial or example on this, I have not seen one but there are lots of forum questions and answers of workarounds of doing this.